# Google Calendar to Google Sheets, Script does not pick up time correctly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

For some reason, the script I run is pulling the event times an hour off. If I have a time of 4pm, it brings it up as 3pm. The event dates and times are pulling as CST, but it is not displaying correctly. Does this line need to be changed somehow to bring up the local time?

I am not sure what to try.  Right now the date/time are pulled using CST, but the output from the script line brings the wrong time.  Could there be something different I have to add to this?

```
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("October 20, 2019 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("November 2, 2019 23:59:59 CST"), {search: ''});


var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
// Uncomment this next line if you want to always clear the spreadsheet content before running - Note people could have added extra columns on the data though that would be lost
// sheet.clearContents();  

// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
sheet.clearContents();
var header = [["EVENT / SHOW", "VENUE / LOCATION", "DELIVERY NOTES", "DATE", "TIME"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,5);
range.setValues(header);


// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var myformula_placeholder = '';
// Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below
// NOTE: I've had problems with the getVisibility for some older events not having a value, so I've had do add in some NULL text to make sure it does not error
var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime(), Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "hh:mma")]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
range.setValues(details);
```

Expected results are to have this pull the exact time that shows on the Google Calendar.

Comment: Perhaps Google Scripts and you Calendar have different time zones.

Comment: I verified both and they are both CST.  But, the Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "hh:mma" could possibly need to be defined more.  I don't know for certain as this is all new for me.

Comment: @Tanaike Can you help with this? Any ideas?

Comment: Can I see more of the code?  Basically, we need a [mcve].  So that we can verify the problem and then try to fix it.

Comment: I ran this code `Utilities.formatDate(events[j].getStartTime(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "hh:mma")` in one of my scripts which I've been using for about 3 years and it works just fine.  The only thing I had to change was index parameter.

Comment: If you can provide me with a [mcve] so that I can see the problem then I will work on trying to find a solution.  Note: I just want a minimal amount of code to produce the problem.  If it's greater than 50 lines put in a little more effort in to reducing it.  This will probably result in you finding the solution and if not I'm sure one of the volunteers here will find it.

Comment: @Cooper, thank you for your help.  

var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("October 20, 2019 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("November 2, 2019 23:59:59 CST"), {search: ''});
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
// Uncomment this next line if you want to always clear the spreadsheet content before running - Note people could have added extra columns on the data though that would be lost
// sheet.clearContents();

Comment: // Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
sheet.clearContents();
var header = [["EVENT / SHOW", "VENUE / LOCATION", "DELIVERY NOTES", "DATE", "TIME"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,5);
range.setValues(header);

Comment: // Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var myformula_placeholder = '';

Comment: // Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below
// NOTE: I've had problems with the getVisibility for some older events not having a value, so I've had do add in some NULL text to make sure it does not error
var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime(), Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "hh:mma")]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
range.setValues(details);

Comment: @Cooper , If I am doing this wrong, please let me know.  I am new to the google scripting and so, there is a learning curve.  Hopefully what I have listed here will help and make sense.

Comment: If you're trying to give me code.  Then please provide it in your question and please format it properly.

Comment: @Cooper , sorry, I had no idea.  I think I got it.  Let me know if you need something more.  Thanks Cooper.

Comment: `myformula_placeholder` is defined and not used,`cal` is undefined and do you really run this without a function declaration?

Comment: I run it right now as you see it there.  It was a script that someone else had created.  I had help from another on here to set the parameters I was looking for, but he doesn't seem to know how to fix this current issue.

Here is the link to that:  https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheet%2Fccc%3Fkey%3D0AkUblBlbq6UEdDVlRXVRclF1amMtYnhHX0oteExBSFE%26newcopy&redir_token=mBTbFVz4jtWrg__wdBmHS6KPEoZ8MTU3MTc4MzE0OUAxNTcxNjk2NzQ5&event=video_description&v=c07hW-_URMk

Comment: I ran both of these lines in some code to get all my events for the next 15 days  and they worked fine with no time errors. `var sd=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ev.getStartTime()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MM dd, yyyy");var st=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ev.getStartTime()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"HH:mm");`

Comment: I also used this format "hh:mma" and that works too. Where did you look to find the script time zone?

Comment: Did you look in the Files/Project Properties for the time zone setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your reference this is the code I was using to test your format strings.

```
function runTwo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var calA=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var html='';
  var today=new Date();
  var s=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate());
  var e=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+15);
  calA.forEach(function(c){
    var events=c.getEvents(s,e);  
    if(events.length>0) {
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />%s<br />',c.getName());
    }
    html+='<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>';
    if(events.length>0) {
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th>',"EVENT/SHOW","VENUE/LOCATION","DELIVERY NOTES","DATE","TIME");
    }
    events.forEach(function(ev){
      var sd=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ev.getStartTime()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MM dd, yyyy");
      var st=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ev.getStartTime()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"hh:mma");
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',ev.getTitle(),ev.getLocation(),ev.getDescription(),sd,st);
    });
    html+='</table>';
  });
  if(html) {
    var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(1000);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "My Event Data");
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No Events Found');
  }
}
```

It loads all event data for each individual calendar in a separate little html table and displays all of them in a modeless dialog.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly.  Does this mean it works or doesn't work?

Comment: Yes it work for me.  But it doesn't really do anything different than what you're doing.   So that's why I asked the question where did you go to figure what timezone the script is set too?

Comment: The first line of my script brings up the dates to pull info from including CST.

Comment: I would think with it listed, it would be pulling from that time zone.  There is a line in the events area:  Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "hh:mma"  Maybe this needs to be modified to specify a time zone?

Comment: Please, go to File/Script Properties to see the Script Timezone. My guess is that it is different than the calendar setting

Comment: That was it!  Thank you so much!  How do I click on Accept for the answer?

Comment: There is a gray check mark to the left of the answer.  Click on it and it will turn green